# Where can I add "already" in "I am going to have gone to bed by the time you come home"?

Tags: adverbs

> I am going to have gone to bed by the time you come home

Where can I add "already" in this question?

Answer (score 1):

You could add it after "am", but your sentence sounds very unidiomatic.
This would be likelier:
"I will already have gone to bed by the time you get home."

Answer (score 0):

You could place "already" after "am", or before "gone to bed" or after "gone to bed".

I'd probably rephrase to avoid the future perfect:

> I'll already be in bed by the time you get home.